# List of list to string

Tags: list, python-2.7

I have  a list of list for example :

```
sample = [['a'],['b']]
```

I want this list to be converted to a string list like

```
sample = ['a','b']
```

I have used lists before but this seems to be bothering me!!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [5]: sample = [['a'],['b']]

In [6]: [item for sublist in sample for item in sublist]
Out[6]: ['a', 'b']
```

or

```
In [10]: from itertools import chain

In [11]: list(chain.from_iterable(sample))
Out[11]: ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't covered all the cases, but:

```
[''.join(x) for x in sample]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loops would be enough -

```
>>> s = [['a'],['b']]
>>> t = []
>>> for a in s:
        for b in a:
            t.append(b)


>>> t
['a', 'b']
```